# Had to click md-button twice to get WebApi call result

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to build a simple MVC WebApp with WebAPI call and AngularJS. Front-end has a md-button, with ng-click method defined in the controller. When ever I filled up the fields and hit the button, it should go to angular Controller => factory => call Web Api and return the result. But after first click nothing is returned, whereas if I click on the same button second time, it gets me data. I am not able to understand why this is happening ?

**Index.cshtml**

```
<md-button ng-click="GetResponse()" class="md-raised md-primary">
  Get Response
</md-button>
```

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.GetResponse = function () {
        debugger;

//Hardcodes the values, but still does not work
        $scope.edm.shortDescription = 'SDesc';
        $scope.edm.detailDescription = 'DDesc';
        $scope.edm.changeType = $("#ddlChangeType")[0].innerText;
        $scope.edm.category = 'CategoryName';
        $scope.edm.application = 'AppName';

        PrepareRequestService.GetFullRequest($scope.edm).then(function (d) {
                                                 $scope.fullRequest = d.data;
                                             }, function (e) {
                                                 alert('Failed');
                                             });

        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.fullRequest));
//This is the line I am getting null first and then value after second click.
    }
```

**Service.js**

```
myAppModule.factory('PrepareRequestService', function ($http) {
    var fac = {};


    fac.GetFullRequest = function (edm) { 
        debugger;
//Here the Api Url is constructing properly
        console.log('http://localhost:17669/api/PrepareRequest/' + edm.shortDescription + '/'
                                                                       + edm.detailDescription + '/'
                                                                         + edm.changeType + '/'
                                                                         + edm.category + '/'
                                                                         + edm.application + '/');

//This is the actual call to API
        return $http.get('http://localhost:17669/api/PrepareRequest/' + edm.shortDescription + '/'
                                                              + edm.detailDescription + '/'
                                                                + edm.changeType + '/'
                                                                + edm.category + '/'
                                                                + edm.application + '/');


    };
    return fac;
});
```

**Web API:**

```
// GET: api/PrepareRequest/sDescription/dDescription/changeType/category/application
        public RootObject Get(string sDescription, string dDescription, string changeType, string category, string application)
        {
            RequestBuilder p = new RequestBuilder();

            RootObject ro = new RootObject();
            ro = p.PopulatePPMParameter(application, sDescription, "Today", "myName", changeType, category);
            return ro;

        }
```

//When tried in browser, this API returns exact JSON format data what I am getting after clicking GetResponse second time. But I need to get that in every click.

Comment: Perhaps you may share some code on what you have done?

Comment: thanks for taking a look. Code added...4 files involved => 1. Index.cshtml, 2. Controller.js, 3. Services.js, 4. WebApi c# file. I have put Angular Module, Controller and Services in separate files.

Comment: Update: When I checked the network tab in developers tool for chrome, it says "Failed to Load response data" just after first request. But it's able to get the data in the above request.